# sending xml string using php curl but not as post parameter

Tags: php, curl, https

:)
I'm trying to send an XML using curl but not as post parameter. what I mean is this.

for example.

the receiving side of that XML won't be able to recieve the XML using `$_POST` variable.

he will need to use the following code:

```
    $xmlStr=null;
    $file=fopen('php://input','r');
    $xmlStr=fgets($file);
```

I want to be able to send an xml string using curl via https.

so the following would be wrong:

```
public static function HttpsNoVerify($url,$postFields=null,$verbose=false) {
    // Initialize session and set URL.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    if ($postFields !=null) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    }
    if ($verbose) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    }
    // Get the response and close the channel.
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

because here i can use `HttpsNoVerify($url,array('xml_file'=>'xml..'));` and that 
will paste it as post parameter. and i want it as post output.

so please I hope i explained myself properly and I explained exactly what I don't want to do.

how can I do what i want to do?

thanks! :)

kfir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just directly pass the xml string as second parameter instead of an associative array item,

```
HttpsNoVerify($url, 'xml ..');
```

This will eventually call

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xml ...");
```

Which will be put in `php://input` for the remote server.